# Proving $\forall x>0, f(x)>0$ using Maclaurin expenssion

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

> Suppose $f$ has a second derivative in $\mathbb R $. Further more: 
>   $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)>0$ and $\forall x>0, f''(x)\geq f(x)$. Prove that $\forall x>0,f(x)>0$

---

Let $x>0$.

Using Maclaurin expenssion, we get for some $c\in(0,x)$: $f(x)=f(0)+f'(0)x+\frac{f''(c)}{2}x^2$

so $\forall x>0, f(x)> \frac{f(c)}{2}x^2$, and we finally need to prove that 
$\frac{f(c)}{2}\geq 0 $, but I couldn't see a way to do so. Maybe my whole approach is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that the set $S:=\{x>0:f(x)\leq 0\}\not =\emptyset$.
Let $x_0=\inf(S)$. Since $f'(0)>0$ then $x_0>0$  otherwise 
$$\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{f(x)-0}{x-0}\leq 0\implies f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}\leq 0.$$
By Maclaurin expansion, there is $0< c< x_0$
$$0\geq f(x_0)=f'(0)x_0 +\frac{f''(c)}{2}x_0^2>\frac{f''(c)}{2}x_0^2\geq  \frac{f(c)}{2}x_0^2\geq 0$$
which implies that $f(c)\leq 0$. Hence $c\in S$. But $0<c<x_0=\inf(S)$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Assume by contradiction that there exists a point $x_0 > 0$ such that $f(x_0) \leq 0$.

Since $f'(0) > 0$ and $f(0) = 0$, then $f$ is strictly positive in a right neighborhood of the origin. Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $x_1 \in (0, x_0]$ such that $f(x_1) = 0$.
On the compact interval $[0, x_1]$ the function $f$ admits a maximum point $x_2$, and $f(x_2) > 0$ (since $f$ achieves positive values), so that $x_2 > 0$.
Moreover, we have that $f'(x_2) = 0$ and $f''(x_2) \leq 0$.

Finally
$$
0 < f(x_2) \leq f''(x_2) \leq 0,
$$ 
a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

I think this approach is doomed.  Not all functions with second derivatives have Maclauren expansions, and there in general they are not valid for arbitrarily large values of $x$.

I suggest that you look at expressions like $f(x) = \int_0^x f'(t)\,dt$ and see what you can infer from them.  (Hint: this is just one relevant step in a solution, but the others are similar.)